# Function with enum return type can not be resolved in a class of C++

Tags: c++, class, enums

1. My check.h file has an enum as a private variable. I do not know what to do to declare enum as a global entity.
2. I declare a function in check.cpp with enum return type. But it is giving the error as follows.

   - Multiple markers at this line
   - Type 'TStatus' could not be resolved
   - ‘TStatus’ does not name a type
   - Member declaration not found

my program is as follows. Can anyone please give me a solution for this.

**check.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "check.h"
using namespace std;


    check::check() { }

    TStatus check::getStatus()
    {
    ......
    }

    check::~check() { }
```

**check.h**

```
#ifndef CHECK_H_
#define CHECK_H_

class check {
private:
    enum TStatus {  ok,sold,defect  };

public:

    check();
    ~check();
    TStatus getStatus();

};

#endif /* CHECK_H_ */
```

Comment: no need to make it global, but it has to be public, otherwise it is unknown to anything but the class itself

Comment: I do not want to declare it global. and  TStatus check::getStatus() is a function of the class. so why it can not access enum.

Comment: ...again: If it is private, it is unknown to any code but the class itself (i.e. you can use the enum only inside the class). If you want to use it as return type you have to make it public! Making it public does not make it a global entity. It is still tight to the class. Anyhow I do not understand why you have problems with defining it on a global scope, it is just a type...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you just need to write

```
check::TStatus check::getStatus()
^^^^^^^
```

because otherwise the compiler does not know where does `TStatus` come from.

See full compilable code here: http://ideone.com/l5qxbK

But note also another problem. Your `getStatus()` is a `public` function, so you will probably want to call it from outside of a class. But you will not be able to do this because the return type is `private`, and thus can not be used outside of the class (bar note below). So you will either need to make the enum `public`, or you can make your `getStatus()` private if it is not used outside of a class.

---

Note: you can in fact use `getStatus()` outside of your class even is your `TStatus` is private — if you do not use the `getStatus()` result; see my ideone code linked above. Though in sensible design such call should not have much sense.

Also, see Vlad's answer on how you can use `auto` to actually store the `getStatus()` results even is `TStatus` is private. Though still better is to make `TStatus` public.

Comment: well ok, you example does compile. But just try to use the return type of the function outside of the class and you will realize that it is not possible.

Comment: @tobi303, yes, I realized this and edited the answer. Though OP did say nothing about using it outside of a class.

Comment: @tobi303, btw, even with private `TResult` the function can be called from outside the class... if its result is not used :) . Though this would be a strange design indeed.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify class name before name `TStatus`

```
check::TStatus check::getStatus()
//...
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

class check {
private:
    enum TStatus {  ok, sold, defect };

public:

    check() = default;
    ~check() = default;
    TStatus getStatus() const;
};

check::TStatus check::getStatus() const { return defect; }

int main() 
{
    auto status = check().getStatus();

    std::cout << status << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
2
```

Comment: Wow, strangely this works despite `TStatus` being private, because `auto` here becomes `int`!

Comment: @Petr  In fact the code does not use explicitly the private name.:)

Comment: Hm, initially I though that it just silently converts to `int`, but no, `auto` seems to allow hiding of type privateness.

Comment: Why not use a trailing return type to avoid typing "check::" twice?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow That's your opinion. I find redundancy less readable. I think you should offer both solutions for future readers

Comment: @KABoissonneault  You are mistaken. It is a scientific opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your function definition as follows:

```
check::TStatus check::getStatus()
    {
        return sold;
    }
```

Demo:http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ca5333f3674d39b

Comment: sorry but you are wrong. In you example the error is only produced because `TStatus::ok` is the wrong way to access it. It should be `check::ok` instead

Comment: .. same problem as in other answer before... try to use the return value of this function outside of the class and you will see that it fails to compile (because the type is only known to the class)

Comment: @tobi303 you are wrong, please check the demo, edited it

Comment: hm I am not using C++11, thus i am not familiar with `auto`. Would be interesting what type it actually is (I doubt its the enum defined in the class). Anyhow, dont you agree that if a class returns some type, this type should be accessible for the caller?